# label selected bars in intraday timeframe over multiple sessions

Tags: pine-script

In intraday time frame, I want to calculate the certain fixed number of bars from user selected starttime and label those bars (even if over multiple sessions).

Problem:

1. It currently stops to count and label once the trading session is over for the day.
2. Need it work for any intraday time frame.

Here is the code which I have made for 5 min time frame but it does not go over to the next trading sessions.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Gann TimeCycle", overlay=true)

IntraColor = input.color(color.new(color.aqua, 55), "IntraColor")

Intra = input(defval=true, title="Intra", group = "Gann Cycles", inline = "Intra")
IntraStart = input.time(timestamp("12 Jan 2023 00:01 +0000"), "Intra StartDate")

z = 1 * (Intra ? 1 : 0)

//plot intra cycle
line.new(IntraStart, close, IntraStart, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart, close, text="i0", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*9*300000, close, IntraStart + z*9*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*9*300000, close, text="i9", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*17*300000, close, IntraStart + z*17*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*17*300000, close, text="i17", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*26*300000, close, IntraStart + z*26*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*26*300000, close, text="i26", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*34*300000, close, IntraStart + z*34*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*34*300000, close, text="i34", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*40*300000, close, IntraStart + z*40*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*40*300000, close, text="i40", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*55*300000, close, IntraStart + z*55*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*55*300000, close, text="i55", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*68*300000, close, IntraStart + z*68*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*68*300000, close, text="i68", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*77*300000, close, IntraStart + z*77*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*77*300000, close, text="i77", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*80*300000, close, IntraStart + z*80*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*80*300000, close, text="i80", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*90*300000, close, IntraStart + z*90*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*90*300000, close, text="i90", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*103*300000, close, IntraStart + z*103*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*103*300000, close, text="i103", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*112*300000, close, IntraStart + z*112*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*112*300000, close, text="i112", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*121*300000, close, IntraStart + z*121*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*121*300000, close, text="i121", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*135*300000, close, IntraStart + z*135*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*135*300000, close, text="i135", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*144*300000, close, IntraStart + z*144*300000, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*144*300000, close, text="i144", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `timeframe.in_seconds()` return the timeframe that is passed as an argument to seconds. You can use it to convert the timeframe of the chart using the `timeframe.period` built in variable:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Gann TimeCycle", overlay=true)

IntraColor = input.color(color.new(color.aqua, 55), "IntraColor")

Intra = input(defval=true, title="Intra", group = "Gann Cycles", inline = "Intra")
IntraStart = input.time(timestamp("12 Jan 2023 00:01 +0000"), "Intra StartDate")

z = 1 * (Intra ? 1 : 0)

currentTfInMiliSeconds = timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period) * 1000

//plot intra cycle
line.new(IntraStart, close, IntraStart, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart, close, text="i0", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*9*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*9*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*9*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i9", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*17*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*17*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*17*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i17", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*26*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*26*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*26*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i26", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*34*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*34*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*34*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i34", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*40*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*40*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*40*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i40", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*55*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*55*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*55*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i55", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*68*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*68*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*68*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i68", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*77*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*77*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*77*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i77", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*80*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*80*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*80*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i80", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*90*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*90*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*90*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i90", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*103*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*103*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*103*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i103", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*112*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*112*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*112*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i112", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*121*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*121*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*121*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i121", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*135*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*135*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*135*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i135", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)

line.new(IntraStart + z*144*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, IntraStart + z*144*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=IntraColor , width = 1)
label.new(IntraStart + z*144*currentTfInMiliSeconds, close, text="i144", xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = IntraColor)
```

Comment: Thank you. Though it works but it still does not print the line after the session ends each day.